# Using image value to choose an image from an array and display it (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a bunch of pictures and I want to display a bigger version of them when they are clicked. What I have right now:

```
    <div class="gallery">
        <div>
            <img src="content/imggallery/img1.jpg" class="oldimg" value="0">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="content/imggallery/img2.jpg" class="oldimg" value="1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="content/imggallery/img3.jpg" class="oldimg" value="2">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var imageData = new Array (3);
imageData[0]="0.jpg";
imageData[1]="1.jpg";
imageData[2]="2.jpg";

$(".oldimg").click(function(){
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
    $("body").append("<div id='newimg'></div>");

    $("#overlay")
    .height(docHeight)
    .css({
        'opacity' : 0.4,
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'background-color': 'black',
        'width': '100%',
        '-ms-filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)',
        'filter': 'alpha(opacity=50)',
        'z-index': 1000
    });
    $("#newimg")
    .css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '50%',
        'left': '50%',
        'background-image': 'url(' + imageData[] + ')',
        'transform': 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        'z-index': 1010
     });
    $("#newimg").click(function(){
        $("#newimg").remove();
        $("#overlay").remove();
    });
});
});
```

Now, how do I get the value of the image, pass it to the array and then to `'background-image': 'url(' + imageData[] + ')'`? Additionally, how do I adjust the `#newimg` size to fit the image? Because `width` and `height 100%` should do it but only with no-reapeat, so where exactly do I put no-reapeat?
The code works but only with fixed height/width and a specific img background i. e. `1.jpg`.
Working example in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bx27sjLL/

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get the image value

```
 $(".oldimg").click(function(){
       var value= $(this).attr("value");
       imageData[value]; // get value 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4wqb20v/5/)**